# Hide WooCommerce empty product categories from WordPress menu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, menu, taxonomy-terms

Based on [Sort WooCommerce product category sub menu items by name ASC in Wordpress menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65668384/sort-woocommerce-product-category-sub-menu-items-by-name-asc-in-wordpress-menu/65671977#65671977) answer code to my previous question, I am able to automatically display child subcategories as menu sub items for some product categories in my WordPress navigation menu.

**My question is:** Is it possible to hide empty subcategories *(sub menu items)*?

*And maybe if possible hide categories that contains only one product that is Sold Out.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additionally [`get_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) with the following parameters:

- `'include'` to include all child terms from `get_term_children()` function as a coma separated string of term ids.
- `'orderby'` with `'name'` attribute to sort terms by name,
- `'order'` with 'ASC' attribute to sort terms ascending,
- `'hide_empty'`with `true` attribute to not include empty terms.

So sorting will be made directly without requiring a foreach loop and you will get also directly an array of WP_Term objects.

The revisited code:

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', 'custom_submenu_product_categories', 10, 3 );
function custom_submenu_product_categories( $items, $menu, $args ) {
    // don't add child categories in administration of menus
    if (is_admin()) {
        return $items;
    }

    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    foreach ($items as $index => $post) {

        if ( $taxonomy !== $post->object ) {
            continue;
        }

        $children_terms_ids = get_term_children( $post->object_id, $taxonomy );

        if( ! empty($children_terms_ids) ) {
            $sorted_terms       = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
                'include'    => implode(',', $children_terms_ids),
                'orderby'    => 'name',
                'order'      => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty' => true,
            ));

            // Loop through sorted child terms to set them as sorted sub menu items
            foreach ( $sorted_terms as $index2 => $child_term ) {
                $item = new \stdClass();

                $item->title            = $child_term->name;
                $item->url              = get_term_link( $child_term, $taxonomy );
                $item->menu_order       = 500 * ($index + 1) + $index2;
                $item->post_type        = 'nav_menu_item';
                $item->post_status      = 'published';
                $item->post_parent      = $post->ID;
                $item->menu_item_parent = $post->ID;
                $item->type             = 'custom';
                $item->object           = 'custom';
                $item->description      = '';
                $item->object_id        = 0;
                $item->db_id            = 0;
                $item->ID               = 0;
                $item->position         = 0;
                $item->classes          = array();
                $item->target           = ''; // <= Missing - Mandatory to avoid an error
                $item->xfn              = ''; // <= Missing - Mandatory to avoid an error

                $items[] = $item;
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> Now is not really possible to hide subcategories that contains only one product that are Sold Out, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) , here you can specify more options, so

```
get_term_children( $post->object_id, $taxonomy );
```

Will become

```
get_terms(array(
  'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
  'parent' => $post->object_id,
  'hide_empty' => true,
));
```

This also has a 'order_by' parameter, that defaults to the name of a term

Comment: Nice attempt **+1**… Yes that could be the right answer, but it doesn't give all child terms as `get_term_children()` does…

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Looked into the `include` argument but didn't quite see how it would fit.