# Hide Empty Categories WooCommerce Not Working

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm by no means the most experienced person with WooCommerce or PHP for that matter. I need to loop through the categories and display all that have products. I'm not sure why, but "hide empty => true" is not working. Here's what I have so far:

```
<?php 
            $args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => "product_cat",
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => true

);
$product_categories = get_terms($args);
foreach( $product_categories as $cat ) { ?>
<?php $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); ?>
<div class="category-wrap">
    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($cat)?>">
        <div class="category-img" style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id ); ?>')" >  
            <div class="shop-now">
                <h5>Shop Now</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <p style="text-align:center;"><strong><?php echo $cat->name;?></strong></p>
</div><?php } ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65684762/hide-woocommerce-empty-product-categories-from-wordpress-menu

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner with WooCommerce too but I have done something similar recently which may help as I notice that you're selecting top level categories, i.e. parent = 0.

```
<?php
  // get top level categories (these have parent id == 0)
  $top_level_categories = woocommerce_get_product_subcategories(0);
  
  foreach($top_level_categories as $top_level_category) {
    ?>
      <h2><?php echo $top_level_category->name ?></h2>
      <ul class="products columns-<?php echo wc_get_default_products_per_row() ?>">
    <?php woocommerce_output_product_categories(array("parent_id" => $top_level_category->term_id)); ?>
      </ul>
    <?php
  }
```

Empty categories are not displayed.